# How to access Type Hints inside of a method after it's called in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I started implementing Type Hinting in a large code base worked on by multiple developers to increase transparency on what functions should expect as arguments.

What I would like to do is also validate that the arguments being passed to the function are the correct types.

This would be easy to do inside the function, but that doesn't seem pythonic. I want to make a utility that can be passed the args and types from the function and raises an exception if an incorrect type is passed for the corresponding arg.

example:

```
def find_integer_sum(a: int, b: int):
    utility.validate_args(args, types)
    return a + b
```

What I want is to somehow pass the args and types to a function without needing to always manually insert `utility.validate_args({a: int, b: int})` as that can get cumbersome.

Is there a way to access args with their type hints?

Comment: This may be useful: https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce

Comment: @rdas thanks, looks like I can start with using `.__annotations__` took a quick peek at the source code

Comment: @hancho your avatar image is getting an error from the website it points to and i cannot find another way to tell you about that.

Answer (score 7):

From the Python [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) documentation, you may use [`typing.get_type_hints()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints).

> `typing.get_type_hints(obj[, globals[, locals]])`
>   Return a dictionary containing type hints for a function, method, module or class object.
>
> This is often the same as `obj.__annotations__`. In addition, forward references encoded as string literals are handled by evaluating them in `globals` and `locals` namespaces. If necessary, `Optional[t]` is added for function and method annotations if a default value equal to `None` is set. For a class `C`, return a dictionary constructed by merging all the `__annotations__` along `C.__mro__` in reverse order.